# Neural network object 'net' gets overwritten. How to update it?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

i'm working on a project dealing with character recognition using artificial neural network, I need to train my neural network object 'net', dynamically, based on the training set I have.

The problem is that each time i train my neural network object 'net', its value is overwritten by the recent training set, and the previous weights and other pertinent data is lost. Need help with updating the net object than overwriting, what functions need to be used. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'dynamically'? It does not matter that you call your net 'net'. I think what you describe is exactly the phenomenon called 'catastrophic forgetting' (http://catastrophicforgetting.blogspot.de/2009/03/i-should-describe-what-catastrophic.html). You could build an ensemble of classifiers (combine multiple neural networks, each is trained on a different data set), merge your training sets or use an incremental training method like online learning (stochastic gradient descent) or use another classifier.

Comment: @Vforquest What would you expect? `net=train(...)` makes an assignement to the left. After training new weights are set.

Answer (score 0):

Move the net object to a new name and continue your work

net1 = net;

Answer (score 0):

The naive way to address the issue is to train your neural net with both the new and old data, if possible.

If not, you can try to make it learn slower -- try to play with the learning rate parameters.